# Port change every Time OPC restart

Tags: dynamic, port, apache-nifi, opc

I have Nifi server connected to an OPC server to retrieve Data and send it to Kafka , the problem I have is that every time OPC server restart the port between Nifi and The OPC change and I loose connection , so I have to determine the new port and ask security team to open the New Port , is there any way to fix this Problem in Nifi ? or it should be fixed in the OPC server ?

Answer (score 0):

What you explain seems normal.

When a client connects to a server normally the client's operating system assigns a random port number to the client's connection, that is normal, the one that is fixed is the port on which the server listens.

If the server reboots you will always lose the connection and the client will have to reconnect ... with a different port number

The solution is that the client tries to reconnect automatically if the connection is lost

Comment: The Client "NIFI" try to connect to the server but I get the error "error while connecting to the OPC server" because of the port , so after I communicate the New port to security team and they open the connection , it works !! there is no fixation of the port to not change the port again ?

Comment: In a TCP connection there are two port numbers, the client port that is automatically assigned randomly by the cliente operating system and the server port that expects connections on a fixed and known port number.
It has no sense to restrict that the client only use a certain port number.

Comment: Okey thank you , so as I understand there is nothing to do from my side , the OPC server admin should change the port to Static not dynamic

Comment: Do not confuse IP address and port number, what is dynamic or static is the IP, not the port number. You should consult someone with good knowledge of IP networks. Thank you.

Comment: Okey Thank you :)